# Erro Apos executar procedure: não exibi saída

Tags: oracle, pl-sql

**Codigo**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE buscaturma(cod NUMBER) AS
  nomeT varchar2(20);
BEGIN

  IF (cod=0)then
    dbms_output.put_line('ZERO');
  ELSE
    SELECT DS_TURMA 
     into nomeT
    FROM TURMA
    WHERE CD_TURMA = cod;

    dbms_output.put_line('NOME: '||nomeT);

  END IF;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        dbms_output.put_line('Não foi possível verificar');

END;
```

**Executar procedure**

```
EXECUTE buscaturma(13);
```

**EXPECTATIVA:**

> 'NOME: '||nomeT

**SAIDA:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Sql Developer

```
Menu
  Exibir
     Saída DBMS
       Botão **+**  
         Escolher conexão
```

Nesta janela serão exibidos os *outputs*.